# IIS Web Deployment: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy, windows-server

Trying to deploy an ASP.net web application to a Windows Server running IIS 7.5. I've followed all the instructions here. Still when I try to test the connection in Visual Studio 2013's Publish Wizard I get the error:

> ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

One thing [the article](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler) does not explicitly mention is that port **8172** must be open on the machine for Web Deploy to work.

I've set an incoming firewall rule on the machine for this port using TCP and now Web Deploy works.

Comment: I've now found [this iis.net article](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/hosting-the-microsoft-web-platform-on-amazon-ec2/amazon-ec2-microsoft-web-platform-images-full-web-server-development-stack) that gives clear step by step instructions for enabling Web Deployment on an AWS server.